# identity server token for webapi authorization error

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I have a number of web api services created that need to get the authenticated user.

I have gotten the id server v3 working such that I can enter /core and /connect/token  and my client gets a token and is passing it back to the server.
single iis server running all of the web app and web services and id server.
when I add the token authentication package I am getting an error that the well known configuration can not be found.
I am looking for what I need to change to make this work so that api calls get an authenticated identity.
I think this is a startup problem but I have my app.map() first and then the app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication() after.
so do I make it wait fro the first to complete ? async ? await ?

Comment: Can you browse to the well-known endpoint in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

ok I am slow, I found an option to delay load the metadata and that fixed that.
now the api calls show that the user is authenticated.

Comment: for demos you can host IdSvr and the Web API together, but for many production scenarios you'd normally keep them in separate hosts. Not sure if that was your issue, or just an ordering thing.